# Nested object assignment in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an object (`baz`) of variable contents. How can I assign a sub-object (`foo`) with a key (`baz`) to that object in one line?

---

**Examples:**

```js
var baz = {}
baz.foo.bar = 1;
console.assert(baz === { foo: { bar: 1 } });
```

(or, in the case where `foo` is already defined)

```js
var baz = { foo: { 1: "b" } };
baz.foo.bar = 1;
console.assert(baz === { foo: { 1: "b", bar: 2 } });
```

Comment: Noting here that yes, I can easily write a function where I can use `nestedAssign(baz, "foo", "bar", 2)`, but I am looking for a built-in solution.

Comment: Did you mean, key `bar`?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do and why.  Are you looking for `Object.assign()`?  Some sort of spread operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible* to put all in one line, though personally I wouldn't recommend it. You're technically doing two pretty different things:

- Assign an object as a property if the object doesn't exist yet
- Assign a property if the object already exists, mutating the existing object

You can assign `baz.foo` or the empty object to `baz.foo`, then assign the `bar` property value to the resulting object:

```js
const baz = {};
(baz.foo ??= {}).bar = 1;
console.log(baz.foo.bar);

const baz2 = {};
(baz2.foo ??= {}).bar = 1;
console.log(baz2.foo.bar);
```

I'd prefer

```
// Create the object if it doesn't exist yet
baz.foo ??= {};
// Assign the new nested value
baz.foo.bar = 1;
```

Code readability is more important than [golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) in most cases.

Comment: Valid point, I was looking to do it in 1 line to make it more readable while less verbose. This seems to work just as well, much better than writing an existing function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case :

`baz.foo = {bar :1}`

And your code works for the second case

(Note that the following code outputs false :

```
a = {b:1}
console.log(a==={b:1})
```

)